# How do I use my grenade/Items in Loadout?

Tags: loadout

Stupid question is stupid, but I have looked in the key bindings and could not figure out which action would allow me to lob a grenade (or use any item, but grenades so far are all I've got).

How do I toss a grenade in Loadout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control used to throw grenades, deploy turrets and use other loadout items is "use equipment", bound to the C key and right bumper by default.

Here's a controls cheat sheet: http://www.loadout.com/game-info/controls/